# Asp.net web API 2 separation Of Web client and web server development

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, cross-domain, iis-express

Our web application is developed by 2 teams. One team works on the client side, with it's own Branch for development, and the other works on the server side, also with it's own development branch. The client and the server are running separately, each one as a website on a different port. The websites are hosted over IIS Express during development, and in production they will run over IIS.

Our ideal situation is that each team can develop completely separately and whenever a develop session is over, both teams merge their change-set to a common Branch in order to integrate, than each team merges back to their development branch, and continues.

In order for a full separation, We have x2 SERVER projects, one to handle the real HTTP requests and another one, a "Stub server" Which responses to all the clients HTTP requests with default values, just in order so that the Client side team can test their code without being dependent on the functionality of the server.

The problem is that both the "Stub server" and the real server and using the same Port which the Client side project is directed to.

This causes many annoying mistakes (mostly for the Server side team) of running the application with the "Stub server" instead of the real one, during reviews, tests etc. The only solution for us is to manually create a virtual directory for the real web server project every time before running / or after finding out we were running the wrong server.

Is there a smarter solution to overcome this annoying problem? That would improve our lives!

If anything I said was foolish / not clear please correct me (I'm new to this), or ask for more details, I'll be glad!

Thanks for helpers!

Comment: From your question I understand that the server-side component is a Web API project. But what about the client? Can you specify what kind of technology is used (MVC, client-side javascript framework, etc.)?

Comment: _The problem is that both the "Stub server" and the real server and using the same Port which the Client side project is directed to._ So why don't you configure the stub on a different port and configure the client to use that port? In the release process of the client team you can add a configuration step in order to let the client talk to the real server and the real port.

Comment: The client side team is using AngularJS and typescript. And we could specifiy different ports, but then when integrating we will have to touch the code and change the port the client is refering and we don't want that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your problem is more related to build automation then server configuration. You should really keep the *stub server* and the *real server* into separate ports, and change that port during some kind of build process of your client.

If you are using AngularJS, then I suggest you to create steps into the build process of your client application using common tools like **gulp** or **grunt**. You could create build processes that will set a global variable or modify a constant (e.g. the API endpoint) and name them **local testing** (pointing your client to the stub server) and **integration** (for the real server).

Please note that you can easily [integrate those build processes into Visual Studio](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2014/10/08/how-to-use-gulp-in-visual-studio.aspx), making them part of your global debug/build process.

Here it is a simple gulp task useful for replacing text inside any file: https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-replace

Comment: That sounds very cool. I'll definitely look into Gulp, but can I ask for a bit more specification? I should have 2 different Gulp build proccesses for my need case? One for each branch?

Comment: I would create one `gulp task` and check the branch name inside it, then modify the URI of your API server consistently. I do not know which VCS do you use, but if is git then you could find [this very useful gulp task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-git) that can give you the current branch name using the `revParse` function (using parameters `--abbrev-ref HEAD`).

Comment: Do you perhaps know how can I get this to work with Tfs source control also?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot help you very much. You could try to implement something similar to `gulp-git` using a combination of [`gulp-shell`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-shell) and `TF.exe` for executing commands directly in the command line, and then parsing the result.